# Issue when calling a PLSQL function in select query when function returns an nested table

Tags: mysql, oracle, select, stored-procedures, plsql

I've a plsql function which I'm calling in my select query something like this:

```
select TEST_PKG.GET_VAL(db.id) as value from test_table db where (some condition lets say)  db.id>11
```

plsql function returns an nested table of type number.
eg : `type test_type is table of number`
test_type  is the return type of my function which is an array of numbers.for a single id it can return multiple results or numbers

now when I execute my query I get column value with output as:

```
schema_name.functionname() i.e sa.GET_VAL() //if no record is found for an  id
and sa.GET_VAL(21,33,11,33) //as output if function returns a value.
```

Now how can I get my hands on the value 21,33,11,33? If I do

```
select * from table (TEST_PKG.GET_VAL(12334))// I get numbers in each row. this is consumable.
```

What can I do in my initial select query to get the values to become consumable? it's also ok if I write the values returned by the select query to some temp table with data type as int and consume from there.
I'm working with oracle 11g.
Any help is much appreciated.any guidance is welcomed.
 ***P.S: I cannot change the function.***

Comment: the declaration 'type test_type is table of number' - is not  associative array, i.e. nested table

Comment: Yes you are correct I made a mistake

Comment: What do you mean "consumable"?  Consumable how?  `SELECT TEST_PKG.GET_VAL(db_id)...` is legal syntax even if `GET_VAL` returns a table type.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: `SELECT CURSOR(SELECT * FROM TABLE(test_pkg.get_val(db.id))) FROM test_table db WHERE...`?  That will return the list of value for each `test_table` record as a cursor instead of a table type.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak I mean easily accessible from java to consume.

Comment: See my answer.  If you use the "as a cursor" option, you'll be able to fetch the value as an `Object` and then cast it to a `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 1):

> > What can I do in my initial select query to get the values to become consumable?

A few ways to `SELECT` PL/SQL functions that return tables:

#### Set up a function that returns `TABLE OF NUMBER`...

```
create type matt_tab_typ IS TABLE OF NUMBER;

create or replace function matt_tab_fnc ( p_id number ) RETURN matt_tab_typ IS
BEGIN
  -- dummy logic
  return new matt_tab_typ(21, 33, 11, 33);
END;
```

#### As a table:

```
select o.object_id, matt_tab_fnc(object_id) 
FROM all_objects o where rownum <= 10;
```

#### As a cursor:

```
select o.object_id, cursor(SELECT * FROM TABLE(matt_tab_fnc(object_id))) 
FROM all_objects o where rownum <= 10;
```

#### As a join:

```
select o.object_id, t.column_value FROM all_objects o 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL  ( SELECT * FROM table(matt_tab_fnc(object_id))) t where rownum <= 10;
```

If you want to consume the results in Java, the second option ("as a cursor") works well.  You can select the `CURSOR` column as an `Object` and then cast it to a `ResultSet` to iterate over and fetch the contents.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper function if you cannot modify TEST_PKG.GET_VAL function. This wrapper function will return a pl/sql sys_refcursor which is less hassle for java (look for articles about how to access sys_refcursor from java).

The wrapper function code is below:

```
create or replace function fn_get_val_wrapper(v_id in number) return SYS_REFCURSOR as
  v_ret_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
begin
  open v_ret_cur for
    select tgv.column_value as val from table(test_pkg.get_val(v_id)) tgv;

  return v_ret_val;

end;
/
```